# React app using Docker and Nginx not showing assets with Redirect when 404

Tags: reactjs, docker, http, nginx

I'm encountering a problem when deploying React (Create-react-app) using Docker,
My setup is, Docker builds the React app and serves it using **Nginx**.

The Nginx config looks as follows:

```
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
```

And the DockerFile looks like:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-deps
WORKDIR /usr/src/front
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.12-alpine
COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/front/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Which works when trying to access: `www.myreactapp.com/something` to `www.myreactapp.com/` so that is correct behaviour, but then every assets inside: `/public/images/` or `/public/fonts/` doesn't show anymore.

Per example this logo doesnt show and no errors on the console:

```
src={`${Config.APP_URL}/images/icons/logo.svg`}
```

Anybody could help pin-point a solution?
Thank you